# Creating Dynamodb composite key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

In Aws lambda function I am storing image And My image is my primary key. But No Case is I can store same image in different function as well like. John can be part of function1 and function2 as well. So when I store in both 2nd one got remove. My table structure is which I got by doing

```
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name athlete_collection
```

Result:

```
"Table": {
        "TableName": "athlete_collection",
        "TableSizeBytes": 77,
        "CreationDateTime": 1528273139.189,
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
            "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
        },
        "StreamSpecification": {
            "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES",
            "StreamEnabled": true
        },
        "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:969213561829:table/athlete_collection",
        "ItemCount": 1,
        "TableId": "8cc40165-5ac2-4aa2-9db4-f06ffad8639c",
        "LatestStreamLabel": "2018-06-13T07:22:00.651",
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "RekognitionId",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "RekognitionId",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            }
        ],
        "LatestStreamArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:969213561829:table/athlete_collection/stream/2018-06-13T07:22:00.651",
        "TableStatus": "ACTIVE"
    }
}
```

And I made this by querying like this

```
aws dynamodb create-table --table-name athlete_collection \
--attribute-definitions AttributeName=RekognitionId,AttributeType=S \
--key-schema AttributeName=RekognitionId,KeyType=HASH \
--provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=1,WriteCapacityUnits=1 \
--region eu-west-1
```

Comment: Can you explain, what do you want to do

Comment: who is John and what is function1 and function2?